# Join query in firestore

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have made a Firestore DB with following example :

```
>Users (collection)
>>userID1(document)
>>>name (field) - age (field)

>>userID2(document)
>>>name (field) - age (field)

and another collection like this 

>Firends(collection)
 >>userID1(document)
>>>userID2 (field) - userID3 (field)

>>userID1(document)
>>>userID2 (field) - userID3 (field)
```

first Question: 
How do I retrieve a query that gets the friends of UserID1 and get their name and age from  users collection .. ??

second Question: 
To retrieve All users I have used FirestoreRecyclerAdapter .. I can use this method after getting the query .. ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perform a simple select query in Firebase Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48752803/perform-a-simple-select-query-in-firebase-firestore)

Comment: Not usfull link .. I want the solution in android and also not about search